# Cordova barcode scanner camera on half screen

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement the `QR reader` in ionic and `cordova my app` using the `BarcodeScanner plugin`. So far I am able to run it on **click of a button**.

I want half the screen of my `app` to **open a camera view** which can be used for reading the `QR` instead of opening a **new frame for QR reading**.

Is it possible, how should I go about it?

Comment: Did you find out how?

Comment: No man gave up on it.

Comment: @Anshul Bhai even I have the use case , I think its not possible without changing the core of the cordova-plugin , maybe we open an issue there ?